# Convert string to Dom node javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

i have this code

```
var tmpEl = document.createElement('div')
tmpEl.innerHTML = stringEl;
return tmpEl.firstChild
```

which i use for converting text to Dom node.
The problem is that if `stringEl` contains `<tr>` tag i must create `table` tag not `div` for this to work.Also if want this code to work with `stringEl` contaning `li` tag i must create `ol` or `ul` insted of `div` tag. Is there any generic for converting string to Dom node?
Best Regards,
Iordan

Comment: If you provide different values of your `stringEl` and what you expect at the end, it might be helpful for understanding your problem.

Comment: I think you underestimate the complexity of this problem. This snippet is useful when you deal with the restricted set of elements, but it's way too loose if intended to be generic. Check the related functions of jQuery (.parseHTML, .buildFragment) to see how it's solved there; hint: it's far from 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function domNode(nodeType, text) {
var node = document.createElement(nodetype);
node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
return node;
}

domNode('p', 'Hello World!');
```

Something like that allows you to choose a tag.

Edit: In fact...

```
function domNode(nodeType, text) {
    var node = document.createElement(nodetype);
    if (text) node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    return node;
    }

var myList = domNode('ul').appendChild(domNode('li', 'This is a list item!'));
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a method of DOM Range designed for this: [`createContextualFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/range.createContextualFragment). It's specified in the [DOM Parsing and Serialization spec](http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-range-createcontextualfragment) and is implemented Mozilla, WebKit and Opera browsers (but not IE, yet).

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/gbWCS/

HTML:

```
<table id="table">
    <tr id="firstRow"><td>One</td><td>Two</td></tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
var html = "<tr><td>Three</td><td>Four</td></tr>";
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(table);
var frag = range.createContextualFragment(html);
table.appendChild(frag);
```